# Ajax Post returning "Object XMLHttpReqest" error

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

Can someone offer some help with my problem please?

I have the following code:

```
        function InsertNewMeeting(tripID, contact1ID, contact2ID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "RetrieveSites.aspx/InsertNewMeeting",
            data: "{'tripID': '" + tripID + "','contact1ID: '" + contact1ID + "','contact2ID', '" + contact2ID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (msg) { alert('ok'); },
            error: function (msg) {alert(msg);}
        });
    }
```

This is meant to call a WebService to post 3 integer values.  The WebService works 100%.

However, when I'm calling the function from the web page, all I get is a "Object XMLHttpRequest" error.

I've examined all parameters that are passed, they are 100% ok.

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing or should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single quotes in your string are all over the place.

The data you send will be this:

```
{'tripID': '[tripID]','contact1ID: '[contact1ID]','contact2ID', '[contact2ID]'}
```

Whereas it appears it should be this:

```
{'tripID': '[tripID]','contact1ID': '[contact1ID]','contact2ID': '[contact2ID]'}
```

Comment: OK, I take on board what you say, yes there's a missing "'" after contact1ID.

Comment: (Sorry, pressed returned by mistake!)  Should the values themselves be within square brackets?

Comment: Mind you, that the object you pass in now, is not valid JSON.

Comment: I've used the square brackets to indicate a data field - I don't know the JSON format, but I've normalised the frmat you were using.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to send a proper json object to the server:

```
function InsertNewMeeting(tripID, contact1ID, contact2ID) {
    var data = {'tripID': tripID, 'contact1ID': contact1ID, 'contact2ID': contact2ID};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RetrieveSites.aspx/InsertNewMeeting",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('ok');
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Mind you that you would need [JSON2](http://www.json.org/js.html) to get JSON.stringify() in browsers that doesn't have support for it.

Another thing is that you'd need to enclose properties in double quotes, as it's not JSON if it's just single quotes. Try running your JSON-string through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) to see if it validates.